# How do I make a UICollectionView's cells wrap when all cells are not the same size?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, word-wrap

I have a UICollectionView, and I want the cells to come out in a grid like this:

[image: Expectation]

I did a bit of work to calculate the sizes of the cells given a 16px padding between cells, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the cells to wrap the way I want to. Here's a screenshot of my current UI. The colors are currently a placeholder while I work out the kinks in the dimensions. The blue will be transparent, and the red will be images.

[image: Reality]

I'm using collectionView sizeForItemAt to calculate the size of each cell.

In the Interface Builder, the collection view has the following settings:

[image: Interface Builder]

I did try reducing the size of the smaller cells, to see if they would pop up (I picture how `float` works in CSS), but it did not help. They just got smaller in the rows they're currently in, until they were small enough to fit 3 small ones on the top right line.

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

## Edit 1:

I just had the idea to set the scroll direction to be horizontal instead vertical, and it's closer, but still not correct. I haven't actually specified that I want 16px gutters between cells, even though that's what the cell sizes are calculated for. How would I go about doing that?

[image: Horizontal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case it is better to implement a custom layout for the collection view by subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout`. More details in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1).